# Service Hosted for Arc Server- Editor Tracking Only Allowed for UTC Time?

Tags: arcgis-server, editing, arcgis-online, esri-geodatabase

I am hosting a service to my server then sharing it to multiple apps/AGOL
I want to track edits so I enabled editor tracking with database_time since all my editors are in my timezone and local. 
However when I go to publish the service I get the error:

*Error: "SEVERITY STATUS CODE DESCRIPTION NAME TYPE DATA FRAME
High [Re-analyze] 00129 Data frame has layers that record Editor Tracking dates in database time zone, but the service does not have time zone information Layers Data Frame Layers"*

Is UTC only allowed for services? if not how do I use database time since it is already enabled?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/publish-map-services/00129-data-frame-has-layers-that-record-editor-tracking-dates-in-utc-and-database-time-zones.htm) editor tracking is only allowed in map services if the tracking date fields are set to UTC. But I've found it to be misleading.

There is an [advanced map service setting](https://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/setting-map-service-properties.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_36B90DE5C96D430FBC9F4E7B338ACC9D) in the parameters section, dateFieldsTimezoneID, that allows you to set local database time. If this is set it allows editors tracking to be set to database time. Just enter the time zone *name*, not the ID, and you should be able to publish.

Comment: ahhh I was entering the ID for Eastern (700) and I was getting publishing errors.

Comment: I used the name and its still recording the edits in UTC time not Eastern Standard US time https://imghost.io/images/2017/07/07/Untitled2.png

Comment: A couple of possible issues. Is your database time set to UTC? I've only used this dateFieldsTimezoneID once but when I did I had to change the databse timezone to get it to work correctly. Also web clients seem to show the data in UTC, desktop clients in local time.

Comment: Hmm tracking editor is set to database time (sql) which is eastern because i i edit in desktop to the FC not in a service it displays the correct time. I'm out of the office now and going to esri user conference next week so it will be a week plus till i get to confirm this.